# Calculating Mass Transfer Coefficient for Vaporization Rate

Tags: environmental-engineering, evaporation

I've been tasked with estimating the evaporation rate of a theoretical spill of 32% HCl solution for the purposes of estimating worst case impact to indoor air quality.  The worst case approach would be to assume that all of the HCl has volatilized and that there is no ventilation.  However, I'd also like to take the approach of estimating the *rate* of evaporation to see what the impacts could be over time.

The formula below estimates the evaporation rate, but I haven't be able to track down how to calculate the mass-transfer coefficient.  Could anyone help steer me in the right direction?

[image: Vaporization Rate Equation]

Comment: Where did you get this? Any decent source will explain all the terms. But that may be a coefficient determined from experimental analysis and ranges will usually be given in the text.

Comment: It’s from the PE handbook published by NCEES. They don’t mention anything about a mass transfer coefficient other than it being a variable so it’s a bit frustrating.

Comment: Then you might consider checking other texts.

Comment: Right, I'm looking for suggestions on texts because thus far I haven't been able to find any.  Do you have suggestions?